# Error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly .... Cannot execute a program

Tags: .net, windows, msbuild

I started to get this error:

error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". Cannot execute a program

when building asp.net projects using vs2019 build tools.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing all Microsoft programs related to .NET and Visual Studio from the computer.
Then I reinstalled the Visual Studio 2019 build tools and it worked.

I suggest to first reinstall Visual Studio 2019 build tools and retry, if it didn't work, go on with removing more programs and retry, I am not sure which one of them needed a reinstallation.